# How to combine all dates for every userId?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table with userId, movieId and date. I'm having issues with my query. I would like to query and list out different date tagged with a movieId under each userId.

```
userId movieId  date
  1     A     1:00PM
  1     A     3:00PM
  2     A     2:00PM
  2     C     8:00PM
  2     C     9:00PM
```

I want something like this

```
UserId --Movie(Time)
  1    A     1:00PM, 3:00PM
  2    A     2:00PM
  2    C     8:00PM,9:00PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `group_concat` function

```
select UserId ,movieId, group_concat(date separator ',') 
from your_table group by UserId ,movieId
```

Comment: Thanks so much. SELECT userId,GROUP_CONCAT(date) FROM table GROUP BY movieId fixed my problem.